powershellスクリプトでバイナリ値に変換したい
powershellスクリプトで指定したテキスト値をバイナリ値に変換し、レジストリに保存されているかの確認を行いたいのですが、どの様なコマンドを使用すればいいのかわかりません。

「バイナリ値」とは何ですか？　意味不明です。

Format-Hex (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility) - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn でしょうか。

前の質問 powershellとの連携について の続きかその一部に関しての見直しでしょうか？ 短い抽象的な質問だと XY問題 のように見えるので、課題となっている内容やデータと書きかけでもよいからスクリプトを具体的に示した方が良いでしょう。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？ そして同じ関連の問題であるならば、前の質問を編集して追記するようにしてください。

レジストリのデータの種類がバイナリ値ということなので
文字列をバイト配列に変換する方法が知りたいということですね？
文字列をバイト配列に変換するには文字コードが何かわからないと変換できません。
例えば   UTF-16 の場合は下記のようにして変換できます。
[string]$string = "Hello World"
[byte[]]$stringBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($string)
$stringBytes

簡単な説明
[System.Text.Encoding]
.Net Framework の Encodingクラス
Unicode
Encodingクラスのプロパティ（UTF-16形式のエンコーディング）
GetBytes
文字列をバイト配列に変換するメソッド（関数）
下記のドキュメントを参考にしましたが、コンソールではうまく動作しなかったので一部変更しています。
about_Using 例 - 型名解決用の名前空間を追加する
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.4#example---add-namespaces-for-typename-resolution
Encoding クラス (System.Text) | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-8.0
このドキュメントにエンコーディングのプロパティがあります。
主な例
ASCII
UTF8
Unicode（UTF-16形式）
UTF32
上記のプログラムコードのUnicodeを変更して試してみてください。
また、Shift-JIS の場合は下記のようにします。
[System.Text.Encoding]$sjisencoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("shift_jis");
[string]$string = "Hello World"
[byte[]]$stringBytes = $sjisencoding.GetBytes($string)
$stringBytes

GetEncodingで指定できるコードページは下記のドキュメントに記述があります。
System.Text.Encoding クラス - .NET | Microsoft Learn
エンコードの一覧
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-text-encoding#list-of-encodings
以上
追記）
下記のドキュメントでは、UTF8に変換して登録していました。
$key = New-Item -Path HKCU:\Software -Name MySoftwareKey

$date = Get-Date -Format 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
$newItemPropertySplat = @{
    Name = 'BinaryDate'
    PropertyType = 'Binary'
    Value = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($date))
}
$key | New-ItemProperty @newItemPropertySplat

レジストリ エントリの操作 - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn
新しいレジストリ エントリの作成
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7.4#creating-new-registry-entries
ご参考までに
追加２）
バイト配列に変換して比較するまでののサンプルコードの１例を記述しておきます。
$regKey = Get-Item 'HKCU:\Software\MySoftwareKey'
$valueName = 'BinaryString'
$w1 = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('Hello World'))
$w2 = $regKey.GetValue($valueName) 

if ($regKey.GetValueKind($valueName) -eq [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::Binary) {
  # Binary
  if ($null -eq (Compare-Object $w1 $w2)) {
    "等しい"  
  } else {
    "等しくない"  
  }
} else {
  "レジストリの値がバイナリでない"
}

（注） この中で $null と比較する時は必ず -eq の左に記述してください。
下記の記事によります。
$null について知りたかったことのすべて- PowerShell　$null の確認
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.4#checking-for-null
